# Changing video resolution on HTML 5.0 video with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

UPDATE: I was using the Fotorama plugin and it seems that the bottom menu was causing the problem. Disabling that menu by putting div-tags around the video-tags made the function for setting resolution work. Thanks for the help and encouragement. For the bottom menu I create a simple one using link buttons that link to a similar page with the next video.

I have written JavaScript code that changes the resolution of a video based on input of a option/select-element. It works. The problem is that it stops working when I put exactly the same code inside a function (so that the code can be executed multiple times - each time option/select-element is changed.)

[Here is an image of the videoplayer and the option/select-element I have added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFguU.jpg)

Here is the code for the option/select-element:

```
<li class="porfolionav">
    <select id="selectQuality" onchange="changeVidQualityFunction()">
        <option value="1080" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Videokvalitet</option>
        <option value="1080" id="1080">HD 1080</option>
        <option value="480" id="480">SD 480</option>
        <option value="320" id="320">SD 320</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Here is the code for the videos:

```
<div class="fotorama" data-width="1209px" data-height="680px" data-allowfullscreen="false" data-arrows="true" data-click="true" data-swipe="true" data-autoplay="false" data-transition="slide" data-clicktransition="slide" data-shuffle="false">
  <video id="video1V" height="680px" controls data-caption="320 OGG" poster="videos/img/thumb1.jpg">
    <source src="videos/test_q_320" id="video1">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  <video id="video2V" height="680px" controls data-caption="480 OGG" poster="videos/img/thumb2.jpg">
    <source id="video2" src="videos/test_q_480.ogg" id="video2">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  <video id="video3V" height="680px" controls data-caption="1080 OGG" poster="videos/img/thumb3.jpg">
    <source id="video3" src="videos/test_q_1080.ogg" id="video3">Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div>
```

And here is the code for the changing resolution (works when not in a function):

```
<script>
    function changeVidQualityFunction(){

    $chosenVidQuality = document.getElementById("selectQuality").value;
    $trulycompletevideolink = document.getElementById("video1").src;
    $step1 = document.getElementById("video1").src.split("_q_");
    //COMMENT: step1[0] is the url from start and including the first part of the filename (not the "_q_"-part and the format)
    $upToVidName = $step1[0];
    //COMMENT: step1[1] is the resolution and format, e.g. 320.ogg
    $step2 = $step1[1].split(".");
    //COMMENT: step2[0] is the resoltion e.g. 720 ,step2[1] is the format (without the dot in front of the format type) e.g. ogg
    $vidresolution = $step2[0];
    $vidformat = $step2[1];

        $vidresolution = $chosenVidQuality;
        $result = $upToVidName+"_q_"+$vidresolution+"."+$vidformat;
         $('#video1').attr('src', $result);
         $('#video1V').attr('data-caption', $vidresolution+" OGG");
         $('#video1V').load();

          window.alert("video1 attr src:"+document.getElementById("video1").src); //shows updated URL

}
          </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there an error or something? You should see if `$result` is actually giving you what you want.

Comment: There is no error from what I can see. The $result gives the correct new URL but the video doesn't get updated and if I right click on it and choose "copy videolink" it gives me the old link and not the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

On your `head` tag place this `<script src="jquery-1.12.2.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` to include jquery library since your are using functions from jquery.
and from this line

```
<select id="selectQuality" onchange="changeVidQualityFunction()">
```

change it to

```
<select id="selectQuality" name="video_selected">
```

and edit your script that follows the rule of jquery, make proper declarations as follows.

```
function changeVidQualityFunction() {
        var ev = $('#selectQuality').val();
        console.log(ev);
    var chosenVidQuality       = $('#selectQuality').val();
    var trulycompletevideolink = document.getElementById("video1").src;
    var step1                  = document.getElementById("video1").src.split("_q_");
    //COMMENT: step1[0] is the url from start and including the first part of the filename (not the "_q_"-part and the format)
    var upToVidName            = step1[0];
    //COMMENT: step1[1] is the resolution and format, e.g. 320.ogg
    var step2                  = step1[1].split(".");
    //COMMENT: step2[0] is the resoltion e.g. 720 ,step2[1] is the format (without the dot in front of the format type) e.g. ogg
    var vidresolution = step2[0];
    var vidformat = step2[1];

        vidresolution = chosenVidQuality;
        var result = upToVidName + "_q_" + vidresolution + "." + vidformat;
         $('#video1').attr('src', result);
         $('#video1V').attr('data-caption', vidresolution+" OGG");
         $('#video1V').load();

      window.alert("video1 attr src:"+document.getElementById("video1").src); //shows updated URL

    }
```

notice that I remove `$` of the variable although this is valid, an declare it with `var` so javascript will know that they are variables.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#selectQuality').change(function(){
            changeVidQualityFunction();
        });
    });
```

What the code do is, it will track for a change on your drop down, if change, the function will execute.

Hope this will help

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work but thanks anyway. I can stream the video (timeline moves forward and there is sound) but the videoimage is static, still the splash/thumbnail image (no video) and if I copy the viedolink it is still the old URL and not the one for the choosen video resolution.

Comment: With the code I posted first: If I also trigger the exact same code as inside the function but when the page loads, it will read the standard input on the options-element which I have now set to 480. So it will load the correct resolution (else it would load 320 by default) and the video works and all. When I then trigger the function by choosing for example 1080 all code seems to execute (I debugged with window.alert(" ")) and but nothing happens with the video, it can still play and works fine but it is still 480 resolution and not 1080 as choosen.

Comment: It seems like the: " $('#video1V').load(); "-line doesn't work inside a JavaScript function for some reason.

Comment: I think I might have found the solution! I will be right back and explain after some more testing.

Comment: I found the problem. It is the bottom-menu that allows you to choose scroll/swipe videos. When that menu is turned of it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Fotorama plugin and it seems that the bottom menu was causing the problem. Disabling that menu by putting div-tags around the video-tags made the function for setting resolution work. Thanks for the help and encouragement. For the bottom menu I create a simple one using link buttons that link to a similar page with the next video.